# AWS Pinpoint - Resource not found as response

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, aws-pinpoint

Trying to send a sms message via pinpoint gives me {Message: "Resource not found"}.

I am calling the endpoint as expected and described in the docs:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/apireference/apps-application-id-messages.html#SendMessages

Here the CURL Request, maybe anyone can spot a problem. Thanks a lot!

`curl -X POST \
  'https://pinpoint.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/v1/apps/328f78f258854f1da353b957bd68ed27/messages' \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
  -H 'Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=XXX/20200109/eu-central-1/mobiletargeting/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=XXXXXXXXXec8b0c04e6ab522c42ecdfa52ad4df7ace4deb1574eb33' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Content-Length: 617' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Host: pinpoint.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: XXXXXXX-49e3-4311-8a50-45391d3ed311,7234e3c3-678e-4687-8d06-11406d96d67b' \
  -H 'User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.20.1' \
  -H 'X-Amz-Content-Sha256: cb53ba323130652362fd17ffa226915ba377b822ee7115b4b3e965b731888401' \
  -H 'X-Amz-Date: 20200109T163151Z' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d '{
    "Context": {
        "string": "string"
    },
    "MessageConfiguration": {
        "DefaultMessage": {
            "Body": "string",
            "Substitutions": {
                "string": [
                    "string"
                ]
            }
        },
        "SMSMessage": {
            "Body": "string",
            "Substitutions": {
                "string": [
                    "string"
                ]
            },
            "SenderId": "string",
            "MessageType": "TRANSACTIONAL",
            "Keyword": "string",
            "OriginationNumber": "string"
        }
    }
}'
{"Message":"Resource not found"}`

Answer (score 1):

The problem was i have been using the wrong region it is us-west-2 not eu-central-1.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/developerguide/tutorials-using-postman-configuration.html

[image]